# what's wrong with my generic type casting?

Tags: java, generics

I have a `Student` class and a `StudentPool` class defined as follows:

```
public class Student {
    public Student copy () {
        return new Student();
    } 
}
```

and

```
public class StudentPool<T extends Student> {
    public T copyStudent(T t) {
        return t.copy();
    }
}
```

thus, the `copyStudent` method cannot be compiled and I have to use un-safe type casting. I cannot understand why Java does regard this as illegal?

**Edit:**
user845279, lcfseth, and Bohemian: I think the following revision to Student may cause the similar scenario, cast a parent class into its child class, but this version can pass compiling:

```
public class Student {
    public <T extends Student> T copy() {
       T rv = null; 
       return rv;
    } 
}
```

**Edit:**
forget the above code: `rv` can be either `null` or un-safely casted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that although `Student` returns `Student` from `copy()`, subclasses would *also* return `Student`... not their own type.

Here's an approach to fix your problem:

```
public static interface Copyable<T> {
    public T copy();
}

public static class Student implements Copyable<Student> {
    @Override
    public Student copy() {
        return new Student();
    }
}

public static class StudentPool<T extends Student> {
    public T copyStudent(Copyable<T> t) {
        return t.copy();
    }
}
```

As a side note, it seems you don't need generics here.

Comment: I'm wondering what a class extending `Student` would look like though. Certainly they can't re-implement `Copyable`, so a subclass's `copy` would still return `Student` when typed generically.

Comment: user845279, lcfseth, and Bohemian: I think the following revision to `Student` may cause the similar scenario, cast a parent class into its child class, but this version can pass compiling:
    <code>public class Student {
     public <T extends Student> T copy() {
      T rv = null;
      return rv;
     }
    }</code>

Comment: They *must* reimplement copyable to call the `copyStudent()` method.

Comment: @Bohemian: You cannot implement an interface twice with different type parameters

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you had a class `SmartStudent` that extended `Student`, and a `StudentPool<SmartStudent>`. In this case `copyStudent` should take a `SmartStudent` and return a `SmartStudent`, however the implementation in `Student` isn't doing this - it's only returning a plain `Student` instance.

**Edit:**

In order to implement the pattern you want, you could give `Student` and all its subclasses a [copy constructor](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12):

```
public class Student {
    public Student(Student other) {
        //copy other's Student fields to this instance
    } 
}

public class SmartStudent extends Student {
    public SmartStudent(SmartStudent other) {
        super(other);
        //copy other's SmartStudent fields to this instance
    }
}
```

and make `StudentPool` abstract:

```
public abstract class AbstractStudentPool<T extends Student> {
    public T copyStudent(T original);
}
```

Each `AbstractStudentPool` implementation would call the appropriate copy constructor:

```
public class SmartStudentPool extends AbstractStudentPool<SmartStudent> {
    @Override
    public SmartStudent copyStudent(SmartStudent original) {
        return new SmartStudent(original);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible solution: `public <T extends Student> T copy ()`

Comment: That's almost certainly not a solution.  It'll let the _caller_ choose the `T`, not the method itself, which is bad.

Comment: this is not really "generic". you have to code a new "pool" for each type of "student"

Comment: @newacct - Feel free to post an alternative solution. I'd be interested, especially if it didn't use reflection.

Comment: @newacct - Anyway, you have to code a new student for each type of student :) It's pretty trivial to include a corresponding "pool" with its 5-6 lines, perhaps as a nested class.

Comment: @PaulBellora seriously? mimic c++?

Comment: @Kejia - Not sure what you're trying to say since I've never coded in c++

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast a Parent Class into its Child Class. Implicit cast only works the other way around. Even by using explicit type casting this is highly likely to generate runtime error.